# How do I write a Vim filter script that I can execute and output editor content as ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to write a filter script for Vim that will execute lines in my editor in a rails context.

So far this kind of works:

~/bin/rails_do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts `bundle exec rails runner "#{STDIN.read}"`
```

Filtering this line in Vim

```
puts 'MyCamelVar'.underscore
```

outputs

```
my_camel_var
```

But filtering this line

```
%w(sdf ssdf d dfdss sdfs).collect{|x| puts "#{x} text" }
```

Results in a syntax error

```
ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in `eval':  unexpected end-of-input, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)

%w(sdf ssdf d dfdss sdfs).collect{|x| puts #{x}
                                               ^
```

Also, filtering multiple lines produces syntax errors.

Looks like it's interpreting the # as a comment start.

If I escape the " it works, but this is almost not worth it at this point:

```
%w(sdf ssdf d dfdss sdfs).collect{|x| puts \"#{x} text\"}
Running via Spring preloader in process 79265
sdf text
ssdf text
d text
dfdss text
sdfs text
```

Comment: your error suggests it's not even registering your last ```}```. I know little about Vim, but have you tried removing the space between the quote and bracket here ```text" }``` ?

Comment: Yeah, my guess it's interpreting the # as a comment